# How to replace second existing patteren in unix file

Tags: unix

I want to replace the second existence of the pattern in unix.
Input File:-

```
12345|45345|TaskID|dksj|kdjfdsjf|TaskID|12 
1245|425345|TaskID|dksj|kdjfdsjf|TaskID|12
1234|25345|TaskID|dksj|TaskID|kdjfdsjf|12|TaskID
123425|65345|TaskID|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12|TaskID
123425|15325|TaskID|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
```

Sample Output file:-

```
12345|45345|TaskID|dksj|kdjfdsjf|TaskID1|12
1245|425345|TaskID2|dksj|kdjfdsjf|TaskID3|12
1234|25345|TaskID|dksj|TaskID1|kdjfdsjf|12|TaskID2
123425|65345|TaskID3|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12|TaskID4
123425|15325|TaskID|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
```

Answer (score 0):

your example does not match your question,
so i'll only show how to replace *every second match* of the given pattern

use `awk`.  it's very powerfull tool for command line text processing

`replace.sh` as follow:

```
cat | awk -v search="$1" -v repl="$2" '
BEGIN {
        flag = 0
}
{
        split($0, a, search)
        len = length(a)
        for (f = 1; f < len; f += 1) {
                printf "%s%s", a[f], (flag % 2 == 0 ? search : repl)
                flag += 1
        }
        printf "%s%s", a[len], ORS
}
'
```

`cat input.txt | ./replace.sh TaskID TaskID1`